# What's the idiomatic equivalent in Scala for C#'s event

Tags: c#, scala

In C#, classes and interfaces can have `event`s:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event Action SomethingHappened;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // yes, i'm aware of the potential NRE
        this.SomethingHappened();
    }
}
```

This facilitates a push-based notification with minimal boilerplate code, and enables a multiple-subscriber model so that many observers can listen to the event:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.SomethingHappened += () => Console.WriteLine("Yay!");
foo.DoSomething();  // "Yay!" appears on console.
```

Is there an equivalent idiom in Scala? What I'm looking for is:

1. Minimal boilerplate code
2. Single publisher, multiple subscribers
3. Attach/detach subscribers

Examples of its use in Scala documentation would be wonderful. I'm not looking for an *implementation* of C# events in Scala. Rather, I'm looking for the equivalent **idiom** in Scala.

Comment: this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814246/in-scala-how-would-i-combine-event-driven-programming-with-a-functional-approac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatic way for scala is not to use observer pattern.
See [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf).

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10635684/406435) for implementation.

Comment: How does saying "don't use the observer problem" help the OP in the slightest (in terms of actually answering his question)?

Comment: I'm guessing that "don't do it like that at all, do it in some related way" is what senia means.

Comment: @KirkWoll : OP upvoted the answer, must be doing something right =)

Comment: @om-nom-nom I'll let you figure that one out.

Comment: @FMM oh, that talk in the third person totally messed me up :-)

Answer (score 2):

[This is a nice article how to implement C# events in Scala](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=21) Think it could be really helpful.

Base event class;

```
class Event[T]() {

  private var invocationList : List[T => Unit] = Nil

  def apply(args : T) {
    for (val invoker <- invocationList) {
      invoker(args)
    }
  }

  def +=(invoker : T => Unit) {
    invocationList = invoker :: invocationList
  }

  def -=(invoker : T => Unit) {
    invocationList = invocationList filter ((x : T => Unit) => (x != invoker))
  }

}
```

and usage;

```
val myEvent = new Event[Int]()

val functionValue = ((x : Int) => println("Function value called with " + x))
myEvent += functionValue
myEvent(4)
myEvent -= functionValue
myEvent(5)
```

Comment: From the question: "I'm not looking for an implementation of C# events in Scala."

Comment: Please, if you post a link, provide at least basic excerpt: as the time goes on, page may become unavailable and future reader wouldn't have any direction to dig into.